# Linking a user through SESSIONs

Tags: php, mysql, session

GOAL: Link SESSION member to preference page.

authenticate.php contains the SESSION link. Using the  (`$_SESSION['mmbrname']`) works on the preferences html page but not when trying to query for a member's row within the db.

The UPDATE_mmbrs_prcss.php "require_once" UPDATEs the member's preferences. First, I need to link the individual SESSION member.

If I replace the $mmbr_prefs variable inside the sql with a member name(username), the query works. But, I loose the flexibility of the established session.

I'm not getting any errors with the code below.

MySQL query:

```
require_once 'includes/authenticate.php';
require_once '../incld_001/UPDATE_mmbrs_prcss.php';
/* BEGIN: Query into mmbrs for $mmbr_prefs */ 

$mmbr_prefs = htmlentities($_SESSION['mmbrname']);

try {
    require_once '../incld_001/db_connect.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mmbrs
        WHERE mmbrname = "$mmbr_prefs"';
        $result = $db->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
}
/* END: Query into mmbrs for $mmbr_prefs */
```

Comment: Could you edit the question (there's a `edit` link below the `php` `mysql` `session` tags) and add the contents of the include files?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a identifier, a `id`, and store it in `$_SESSION` and have the same id for each member in the table. So you will need to add a id column to the members table and store this in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: A bit over my head. Is "id" same as a "key"? I do have a member_key column in the members table which relates to each logged on individual in the $_SESSION. I also have code built which requires a new mmbrname be generated to avoid the possibility of conflict. Using the key would probably be more accurate. --- I'm not sure how changing an identifier would resolve my issue? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Ok if you already have a unique identifier for members like a key - use that in SESSION. Store an additional key to track current preference page.